# Where does the asynchronous operation run in an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

Does the asynchronous operation of an `AsyncTask` run in `DoInBackground` or `OnPostExecute`?

```
public class Task1 : AsyncTask
{
    protected override void OnPreExecute()
    {
    }

    protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
    }
}
```

Update

**What I think I meant to ask was if the routine/procedure/task that runs in `DoInBackground` is necessarily a thread, or is it more of an abstract concept of a task and if so is it scheduled to run as such (i.e. can it also be configured to run on the main thread).  Similarly, is the "continuation" that runs in `OnPostExecute` also considered a task, since it runs on the main thread, but can also be "scheduled" to run with other "task's" on the same thread (like a click handler or on a lifetime override like onResume)?**

Comment: it does in doInBackground, preExecute and postExecute does in UI Thread https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: @JoaquinAlvarez But `doInBackground` runs in a separate thread, off of the UI, so is that "asynchronous", or is it when `postExecute` is scheduled to run on the UI, along with say a click event handler?

Comment: I think the async part is doInbackGround since its a separated thread, meawhile postexecute and preexecute uses UI Thread

Comment: @JoaquinAlvarez But isn't `doInbackGround` running "in parallel"?

Comment: @JoaquinAlvarez https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/#comment-4375

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133574/how-to-articulate-the-difference-between-asynchronous-and-parallel-programming check this answer

Answer (score 1):

asynchronous done in `DoInBackground()` and `onPostExecute` You get the result and its UI thread

Comment: `DoInBackground` runs in it's own thread, and `onPostExecute` back onto the UI/Main thread, correct?

Comment: Yes. That`s why DoInBackground called background thread. And it not interrupt anything on main thread

Comment: So `DoInBackground` is running "out-of-sync" technically, but more like "in parallel", to the UI thread. However `onPostExecute` is scheduled on the UI thread, along with whatever may be currently running, either before or after it, which is more like "out-of-order", correct?

Comment: Yeah. Exactly .

Comment: `onPostExecute` waiting for the result which is processing in `DoInBackground`.

Answer (score 1):

These are the 4 steps a task goes through when an asynchronous task is executed:

1. `onPreExecute()`, invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed.
2. `doInBackground(Params...)`, invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing.
3. `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`, invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...).
4. `onPostExecute(Result)`, invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes.

As per documentation `doInBackground(Params...)`:

> doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread
>   immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
>   to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
>   parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
>   result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
>   passed back to the last step. This step can also use
>   publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
>   These values are published on the UI thread, in the
>   onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.

[Async Task | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

To answer your question, any background computation takes place in the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: So would you say `doInBackground`, which runs within it's own thread concurrent to the UI thread, is the asynchronous operation, or would you say the "continuation" of it ran within `onPostExecute` is?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Any background computation should be executed in the `doInBackground` method

Comment: But how is `onPostExecute` ran on the same thread as say a click event that comes right before it? Are both of these "tasks" scheduled to run on the same thread by some task scheduler?

Comment: `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` are invoked on the UI thread. Have also in mind that the task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.).